# Chamar método por comando string

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou uma barra de comandos em uma aplicação com diversas funções presentes em botões numa ribon. Grande parte destas funções devem poder ser executadas por meio de comandos, exemplo:

> ```
> Botão "Salvar" -> Método "Save()"
>
> Comando "sv" -> Método "Save()"
> ```

Eu sei que é possível buscar o método pelo nome e o invocar, mas nesse caso o comando não terá o mesmo nome do método.

Existe alguma forma de na definição do método definir o comando, como logo abaixo e o invocar por meio desse comando?

```
    [Command="sv"]
    private void Save()
    {
        // Save method
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se há uma forma melhor no WPF, mas poderia utilizar um dicionário com os comandos, Veja:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
        public static void Main()
        {
            //monta o dicionário com os comandos...
            cmd.Add("m1", () => { Metodo1(); });
            cmd.Add("m2", () => { Metodo2(); });


            ChamarMetodo("m1");
            ChamarMetodo("m2");

        }
        static Dictionary<string, Action> cmd = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

        static void ChamarMetodo(string cmd_key)
        {
            if (cmd.ContainsKey(cmd_key))
            {
                cmd[cmd_key].Invoke();
            }
        }

        static void Metodo1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("metodo 1");
        }

        static void Metodo2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("metodo 2");
        }
    
}
```

Sendo possível ainda, utilizar um enumerador pra ter os comandos inclusive facilitando no desenvolvimento:

```
public class Program
{
        static Dictionary<ECmd, Action> cmd = new Dictionary<ECmd, Action>();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            cmd.Add(ECmd.Metodo1, () => { Metodo1(); });
            cmd.Add(ECmd.Metodo2, () => { Metodo2(); });


            ChamarMetodo(ECmd.Metodo1);
            ChamarMetodo(ECmd.Metodo2);

        }

        static void ChamarMetodo(ECmd cmd_key)
        {
            if (cmd.ContainsKey(cmd_key))
            {
                cmd[cmd_key].Invoke();
            }
        }

        static void Metodo1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("metodo 1");
        }

        static void Metodo2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("metodo 2");
        }
}

enum ECmd
{
    Metodo1,
    Metodo2
}
```